# Get fields from checkout form into calculate_shipping

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm creating a custom shipping calculator for my WooCommerce store. I need to collect some extra form data from the user to calculate the shipping properly.

I have the form fields added to `woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details`. I can probably get this into the cart page without much trouble once I figure out the checkout page functionality, so let's focus on this.

I have a class extending `WC_Shipping_Method` with a `calculate_shipping` method a la [this tutorial](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipping-method-api/).

In that method, I want to use the extra form data (plus the destination) to calculate the shipping for that customer. Right now I just have this adding a dummy rate, which shows up.

I also created a custom `cart-shipping.php` file to not show any inputs for the available method in the order review cart, just the label and cost. Since the picking happens in my custom form, having options here is unnecessary.

1. Am I doing this right, or is this approach super hacky?
2. If this is the correct approach, how do I access the extra form fields inside the `calculate_shipping` method?

**Have tried**

Named the final options in my custom form `shipping_method_*` which triggers the `wc-ajax=update_order_review` call... which inits my custom shipping method class, but does not appear to ever call the `calculate_shipping` method anyhow. The only time this method seems to be called is when I'm actually adding a product to the order.

**Also tried**

Defined all of my possible delivery options and added them in calculate_shipping like `$this->add_rate( $rate );`. I think then I can somehow select one (force the user into one) when the cart updates via `update_order_review` ajax call? Again, the set option should be determined by these fields the user interacts with on the checkout form. But I haven't figured out how to set the shipping on that action yet.

Comment: This may help https://github.com/valdeirs2/woocommerce-shipping-calculator-in-product/blob/master/includes/ajax-postcode.class.php

Comment: If you just want to get the submitted value from within the `calculate_shipping()` method, then you could access it using `$_POST['field_name']`. But then, I guess you already know that?.. And are you aware that WooCommerce saves the *calculated* shipping rates in the WooCommerce session, and only calls the `calculate_shipping()` method when for example the shipping address is changed?

Comment: @SallyCJ Sorta aware now, I had a separate question about that... I was trying to figure out lots of things here. I am grabbing the post value in `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review` now and storing in the session, then grabbing it later. I suppose I could grab the POST data right in the `calculate_shipping` method, I can't think of a reason why I didn't do that to start with. If you want to put that as an answer, I'd take it.

Comment: I've posted an answer. I hope you'd see it soon.. :p But honestly, I hope that it helps other people as well. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `calculate_shipping()` is *not always* called

First off, you should know that the `calculate_shipping()` method of your shipping method class will only be called when the shipping rates are calculated for the first time (in the current WooCommerce session), each time after a product is added to the cart, and whenever the shipping address is changed — from the cart or checkout page.

But of course, a plugin or custom code can *programmatically* call the method (or re-calculate the rates) at any times. However, the default behavior is as follows:

> Rates are stored in the session based on the package hash *to avoid
>   re-calculation every page load*.

And the `calculate_shipping()` method is executed by the `WC_Shipping` class through its [`calculate_shipping_for_package()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping.html#_calculate_shipping_for_package) method. In fact, the above quote was taken from the description of `WC_Shipping::calculate_shipping_for_package()` which calls [`WC_Shipping_Method::get_rates_for_package()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Method.html#_get_rates_for_package) and eventually the `calculate_shipping()` method in your own class.

### How to get the submitted value of a form field in the checkout form from the `calculate_shipping()` method

So if you have this in the checkout form:

```
<input type="text" name="my_field"...>
```

Then you can get the submitted (`POST`ed) value using either the `$_POST` superglobal or the `WC_Checkout::get_value()` method:

1. `$_POST['my_field']`
2. `WC()->checkout->get_value( 'my_field' )`

It's as simple as that. :)

---

**To ensure calculate_shipping is called**

Run something similar to the following to clear out the session information, which will indicate that calculation still needs to be done. Be aware that if you do this on every page, it will mean that the shipping is constantly being recalculated when it doesn't need to be.

```
$packages = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();
foreach( $packages as $package_key => $package ) {
    $session_key  = 'shipping_for_package_'.$package_key;
    $stored_rates = WC()->session->__unset( $session_key );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @RandyHall. And +1 to the (helpful) question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this, but currently I am making this work by setting a session value on `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review` and then accessing that value in my `calculate_shipping` method.

Answer (score -3):

Looking at the WooCommerce documentation, it seems their desired way for you to access things such as user location from the `calculate_shipping` function is to use their Settings API. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/settings-api/. Read the docs to see exactly how, but here is a simplification:

---

Read the location using

```html
$this->init_settings();
$this->location = $this->settings['location'];
```

---

Write/Set the user's location with this table:

```html
<?php function admin_options() {
     ?>
    <h2><?php _e('You plugin name','woocommerce'); ?></h2>
     <table class="form-table">
     <?php $this->generate_settings_html(); ?>
     </table><?php
     }
```

The table would be made with

```
function init_form_fields() {
     $this->form_fields = array(
     'location' => array(
          'title' => __( 'Location', 'woocommerce' ),
          'type' => 'text',
          'description' => __( 'This is the users address.', 'woocommerce' ),
          'default' => __( 'none', 'woocommerce' )
          )
     );
}
```

Comment: I'm... not sure how this is relevant. This is for creating fields for the admin options... I'm trying to get extra information at checkout.